# Using Scanner to add to empty Object

Tags: java, object, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to add user input to an empty object, but I'm getting null. I think I set the scanner up properly, but I'm not sure on that. I'm not sure how the scanner should be set up to be linked to the empty object. I have setters and getters set up on another class.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class StudentRecordTestHarness
 {
      public static void main (String []args)
      {
           StudentRecord sr1 = new StudentRecord ("Tim", "Lost", 12345, 75);

           System.out.println("First Name: " + sr1.getFirstName());
           System.out.println("Last Name: " + sr1.getLastName());
           System.out.println("Student ID: " + sr1.getStudentID());
           System.out.println("Number Grade for Course: " + sr1.getGradeCourseOne());
           System.out.println("Grade Converted to Letter: " + 
                     sr1.GradeLetter(+sr1.getGradeCourseOne()));

           StudentRecord sr2 = new StudentRecord();
           Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
           System.out.println("Please Enter Student's First Name: ");
           String setFirstName = userInput.nextLine();

           System.out.println("New Student First Name: " + sr2.getFirstName());
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting `sr2.firstName`; you're just creating a new local variable `setFirstName`, which then contains your input.

The following sets the first name of the student record:

```java
String setFirstName = userInput.nextLine();
sr2.setFirstName(setFirstName);
```